# Making library from react native. Then add this library to existing native app (Swift, Android)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

is it possible to make a library from react then add it into some existing native code?

- If yes, can you give me some ways or links that I can refer.
- If no, can you give me some evidences with Sources.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Need more information. Are you talking about a pure javascript library? A library for React that you also want to use in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would be interested by : [Git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

It allows you to add a dependency to your git repository which is another repository.
You should be able to have a Swift (or Android) git repository that uses the react-native repository as a submodule.